# What is the use of timer control?

Tags: asp.net

I know update panel in ajax control.What is used of timer control.I came across the Web application called a1,inside that there are 3 page p1,p2,p3
respectively.P3 contain code for update progress and for file to download that code is in timer1_tick() function.Inside a1 there is one folder called f1.In f1,there is s1 page.In s1's aspx.cs file ,inside the button click event,I am redirecting to p3. Response.Redirect(@"~\p3.aspx", false);
But s1 does not contain update progress,timer control.Does it fine?

Comment: From MSDN - Performs asynchronous or synchronous Web page postbacks at a defined interval. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer.aspx)